# Show .html in angular application

Tags: html, angular

I create a .html in my angular application

**.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>TEST</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to know if it's possible in an angular component to show in a `div` for example the content of the **.html** file

It will look like this :

```
<h1>Manual</h1>
<div>
    // HTML CONTENT
</div>
```

Comment: yes its possible but sounds like you're trying to check 'working with angular' while actually doing non angular code . you sure that's smart ? were missing the context here.

Comment: @Stavm All my project is in angular but I create a Manual with BlueGriffon so I have a .html file and I wanted to know if I can use it or if I have to do it again with angular

Comment: I think your question is about using the very basic angular features like Master/Detail components. Check more about it here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3. Like the answer to this question, you will need to create the component to put there your html.

Answer (score 2):

You can if they are different components.

With Angular, at the top of a .ts file of a component (say example-one), there will be  a section looking like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example-one',
  templateUrl: './example-one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example-one.component.css']
})
```

To insert the HTML content of example-one into another html file, you would add it like any other element. In your case,

```html
<h1>Manual</h1>
<div>
    <app-example-one></app-example-one>
</div>
```